# Select option with selected values returning duplicates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a old selected value and show it inside a select option, as well as a non selected value, however, when i try to compare then it doesnt seen to work, so far i can only get duplicates. What's the best way to implement it?

That's how my code look like.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $roles = Role::get();
    $permissions = Permission::get();

    return view('role.index', compact(['roles','permissions']));

}
```

Role View:

```
@foreach($role->permission as $permissioninrole)
    <option name="permissions[]" {{ old('name', $permissioninrole->name) == $permissioninrole->name ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{$permissioninrole->id}}">{{$permissioninrole->name}}</option>
@endforeach

@isset($permissioninrole)
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
        @if($permissioninrole->name != $permission->name)
            <option class="rem" name="permissions[]" value="{{$permission->id}}">{{$permission->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endisset

@empty($permissioninrole)
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
        <option name="permissions[]" value="{{$permission->id}}">{{$permission->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
@endempty
```

How it looks. HTML

```
<option name="permissions[]" selected value="15">role-create</option>
<option name="permissions[]" selected value="16">role-read</option>
<option name="permissions[]" value="15">role-create</option>
<option name="permissions[]" value="16">role-read</option>
...
```

How it should be if role 'x' has permission role-create.

```
<option name="permissions[]" selected value="15">role-create</option>
<option name="permissions[]" value="16">role-read</option>
...
```

Comment: It looks like you are using incorrect attributes for your `option` attribtues (or you must be using some library, are you?). You can find all the possible attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes). Also it would be wise to prevent duplicate values in your options. Maybe it would be a good idea to create the array of options before hand. Could you show is the part of your `select` as well?

Comment: im only using get() in my controller, i will try to create an array as you said. Im using bootstrap select.

Comment: thanks @ThomasVanderVeen 
I made an array as you said and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
@foreach($permissions as $key => $value)
    <option name="permissions[]" {{ in_array($key +1, $role->permission()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```